# Generating a list of lists of Int with QuickCheck

Tags: quickcheck, haskell

I'm working through [Real World
Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) one of the
exercises of chapter 4 is to implement an `foldr` based version of
`concat`. I thought this would be a great candidate for testing with
QuickCheck since there is an existing implementation to validate my
results. This however requires me to define an instance of the
`Arbitrary` typeclass that can generate arbitrary `[[Int]]`. So far I have
been unable to figure out how to do this. My first attempt was:

```
module FoldExcercises_Test
where

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Batch

import FoldExcercises

prop_concat xs = 
    concat xs == fconcat xs
    where types = xs ::[[Int]]


options = TestOptions { no_of_tests = 200
                      , length_of_tests = 1
                      , debug_tests = True }

allChecks = [ 
              run (prop_concat)
            ]

main = do
  runTests "simple" options allChecks
```

This results in no tests being performed. Looking at various bits and
pieces I guessed that an `Arbitrary` instance declaration was needed and
added

```
    instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary [[a]] where
    arbitrary = sized arb' 
        where arb' n = vector n (arbitrary :: Gen a)
```

This resulted in ghci complaining that my instance declaration was
invalid and that adding -XFlexibleInstances might solve my problem.
Adding the `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XFlexibleInstances #-}` directive 
results in a type mismatch and an overlapping instances warning.

So my question is what's needed to make this work? I'm obviously new
to Haskell and am not finding any resources that help me out.
Any pointers are much appreciated.

## Edit

It appears I was misguided by QuickCheck's output when in a test first manner `fconcat` is defined as

```
fconcat = undefined
```

Actually implementing the function correctly indeed gives the expected result. **DOOP**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[Int]]` is already an `Arbitrary` instance (because `Int` is an `Arbitrary` instance, so is `[a]` for all `a`s that are themselves instances of `Arbitrary`). So that is not the problem.

I ran your code myself (replacing `import FoldExcercises` with `fconcat = concat`) and it ran 200 tests as I would have expected, so I am mystified as to why it doesn't do it for you.  But you do NOT need to add an `Arbitrary` instance.

Comment: i concur.  this worked fine for me in ghc 6.10.4 on OSX Leopard